# revert to previous merged-branch commit without loss any version

Tags: git, git-flow

My commit history is

`A->B->C(head)`

If I want to revert to `B` without losing version `C`.
(make all the data is identical to `B`)

(But B and C are merged commit )

`A->B->C->B(head)`

I use the `git flow` to develop my project

I want to revert to `6450851e7a51f868da414467b42b0c072718f5b9`

and do the following command  but got an error.

How could I get it ?

```
(develop)$ git revert 6450851e7a51f868da414467b42b0c072718f5b9
error: Commit 6450851e7a51f868da414467b42b0c072718f5b9 is a merge but no -m option was given.
fatal: revert failed


*   f831a96 - (HEAD, tag: 1.1, origin/master, master) Merge branch 'release/1.1' (7 days ago)
|\
| * 277bafc - Release 1.1 (7 days ago)
| *   57a4374 - Merge branch 'feature/add_expired_time_and_restore_sorting_cart_bug' into develop (7 days ago)
| |\
| | * 3866d1d - Remove the larger input field (7 days ago)
| | * 879c12e - Remove the insert new item at first function (7 days ago)
| | * bbd7b2b - remove the change password function (7 days ago)
| | * bc4a6fa - add expired time functionality (7 days ago)
| |/
| *   6450851 - Merge branch 'feature/readable_format' into develop (7 days ago)
| |\
| | * cac4083 - make the line space in table more dense (7 days ago)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

First, if you have merges, then your commit history is more complicated than just `A->B->C`.

However, hopefully `C` is not a merge commit.  If that's true, then you want to run:

```
git revert hash-of-commit-C
```

(`git revert` takes the hash of the commit to *undo*, **not** the commit you want to *revert to*).

Comment: unfortunetly, it is a merge commit

Answer (score 0):

As you want to revert a merge, you need to tell git which parent of the merge commit is the mainline you want to preserve:

```
git revert -m 1 6450851e7a51f868da414467b42b0c072718f5b9
```

You will find more information here: http://git-scm.com/blog/2010/03/02/undoing-merges.html